# IOS code to change table html logic

Tags: html, objective-c

I am developing mail sending use objective-C, the format send is html

Here is my code:

```
NSString *content = @"<table style=\"width:100%\">";
int i = 0;
    for (RecipeIngradientVo *object in listIngredients) {
        NSString *ingreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.recipeIngradientVoDescription];

        if(i == 0){
            content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<tr style=\"height:10px;\"> <td valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left:20px\"> <li>%@</li> </td>", content, ingreString];

            i++;
            NSLog(@"i : %d", i);
        }else{

            content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<td valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left:20px\"> <li>%@</li> </td> </tr>", content, ingreString];
            i = 0;
            NSLog(@"i : %d", i);
        }
    }
content = [content stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];
```

this code will display like

1     2

3     4

5     6

7

But i have to change to

1     5

2     6

3     7

4

I am stuck in this logic, plz help

Comment: You can solve this by changing the order of your array `listIngredients`

Comment: Otherwise you need to use a loop that isn't fast-enumeration and you'll need to use `objectAtIndex` logic and add the array's .count/2 (floored) to the index you are checking as you loop from 0 upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer based on  @Albert Renshaw help :)

Here is my code:

```
while (index < listIngredients.count)  {
        NSLog(@"index: %d", index);
        if(i == 0){
            indexToUse = index;
            RecipeIngradientVo *object = [listIngredients objectAtIndex:indexToUse];
            NSString *ingreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.recipeIngradientVoDescription];
            content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<tr style=\"height:10px;\"> <td valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left:20px\"> <li>%@</li> </td>", content, ingreString];

            i++;
            NSLog(@"indexToUse : %d", indexToUse);
        }else{
            indexToUse = indexToUse + round((listIngredients.count + 0.5)/2);
            if(indexToUse >= listIngredients.count){
                NSLog(@"indexToUse it max : %d", indexToUse);
                content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ </tr>", content];
                break;
            }
            RecipeIngradientVo *object = [listIngredients objectAtIndex:indexToUse];
            NSString *ingreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.recipeIngradientVoDescription];
            content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<td valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left:20px\"> <li>%@</li> </td> </tr>", content, ingreString];
            i = 0;
            NSLog(@"indexToUse : %d", indexToUse);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be cleaned up a lot more, look into `modulo` for flipping instead of that if-else statement. But generally speaking you will want to pull from your array manually like so:

```
NSString *content = @"<table style=\"width:100%\">";
int i = 0;
int index = 0;
    while (index < listIngredients.count) {

        if(i == 0){

int indexToUse = index;
RecipeIngradientVo *object = [listIngredients objectAtIndex:indexToUse];
        NSString *ingreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.recipeIngradientVoDescription];

            content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<tr style=\"height:10px;\"> <td valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left:20px\"> <li>%@</li> </td>", content, ingreString];

            i++;
            NSLog(@"i : %d", i);
        }else{

int indexToUse = index+floor(listIngredients.count/2);
RecipeIngradientVo *object = [listIngredients objectAtIndex:indexToUse];
        NSString *ingreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object.recipeIngradientVoDescription];

            content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<td valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left:20px\"> <li>%@</li> </td> </tr>", content, ingreString];
            i = 0;
            NSLog(@"i : %d", i);
        }
index++;
    }
content = [content stringByAppendingString:@"</table>"];
```

Comment: hello, i working with your code, when index == 6, then indexToUse = 13.   It cause crash because listdata.count = 13